# Build menus at runtime in word vba, using onAction and Parameters

Tags: vba, ms-word, ms-office

I am building a big menu with many of sub and sub sub menus at runtime in VBA (word)
I want to let every tail of the menu (we can just say every menu item) to be linked with sub so when menu item with caption xxx be clicked the xxx show up in message box

while building the menus
I used

```
myMenu.Caption ="xxx"
myMenu.onAction ="MySub"
myMenu.Parameters = myMenu.Caption
```

searching for how to use the .parameters
 I found that I need to mention the menu object in MySub !!! (as MySub didn't take a parameter)

so this will not solve it :(
I want to pass the caption to MySub, so all menus work just like I mentioned above,
like this `MySub(menuCaption as string)`

but I found that I have to use it like this

```
MySub()
  Msgbox myMenu.Parameter
end sub
```

so in MySub if I need to mention myMenu then how it could be dynamic and work on all menu items,

Here is the sub which builds my menus

```
Sub BuildCommentsMenu()
 Dim men As CommandBarControl
 Dim i%
 Do
 'test line to be removed
 'If i > 299 Then Exit Do

    If Len(commentsObjs(i).comment) = 0 Then Exit Do
Set men = categoriesObj.getMenuUponName(commentsObjs(i).Type_).Controls.Add(msoControlButton, , , , True)
    With men
        .caption = Left(commentsObjs(i).comment, 200)
        If Len(commentsObjs(i).comment) > 200 Then .caption = .caption + "..."
        .Visible = True
        'uncomment next line when you put the functions
        .OnAction = "fnMen" & CStr(commentsObjs(i).ID)
    End With
Set commentsObjs(i).CommentMenu = men
    i = i + 1
 Loop
 End Sub
```

[image]
any clue ??

Thank you so much,

Comment: right, it seems that you need to pass either the menu object to your `MySub()` or pass the caption like `MySub(caption as String` and then `MsgBox caption`.

Comment: What version of Word are you using?

Comment: Great mehow, but I can't do this, my version is word 2011 for Mac

Comment: @mehow or let's say, how I can do that? my tries failed

Comment: @amrosama have a [**READ**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa263527(v=vs.60).aspx)

Comment: @mehow this is great, and I know about this, but the question is how to pass a parameter in my case?? or how to pass parameter to .onAction, I tried with this a lot but no luck :(

Comment: Right, what `menus` are you talking about? Can you show more of your code? Specifically when how you declare and instantiate your `myMenu` variable

Comment: @amrosama can you elaborate and define the `menus` youre talking about?

Comment: I put the sub where I build my menaus BuildCommentsMenu(check it above please),

Comment: @mehow I work on word 2011 for mac and I am building a standard office menus using VBA

Comment: @OlleSjögren my version is word 2011 for mac

Comment: please define *`standard office menus`*? I have no clue what that means.. can you edit your question and post a screenshot?

Comment: @mehow screenshot uploaded

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to build all your menus like this

```
myMenu.Caption ="xxx" 'change this caption every time
myMenu.onAction ="MySub"
myMenu.Parameters = myMenu.Caption
```

Then, in your sub, use

```
Public Sub MySub()
    MsgBox CommandBars.ActionControl.Parameter
End Sub
```

This always give you the caption of the menu which was clicked.